# Converting a cursor in to a stream to fit in reactive webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive

I have a web app developed in Spring boot reactive. I have to unzip a file and save the file information in database. All the executions are completely reactive ( flux/mono ).

Now I have a code to unzip, using Java utils

```
  public void Flux<AppFile> saveFiles(){
       ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream( BASE_URL + filename ));
     
       while( zis.getNextEntry() != null ){
         reactiveRepository.save( new AppFile( "name", "description", zipEntry.getFileName()); 

      }
....
  return Flux.just(..); // not a clean way to return a flux.
  }
```

As you can see, the while looping is standard way , but the entity save is reactive .

How do I convert this iterator in to a stream, so that I can processes everything in reactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
return Flux.<ZipEntry>generate(sink -> {
                ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
                ZipEntry zipEntry;
                try {
                    if ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) == null)
                        sink.complete();
                    else
                        sink.next(zipEntry);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    sink.error(new RuntimeException(ex));
                }
            }).map( e -> new AppFile("name", "description", e.getName()))
            .doOnNext(reactiveRepository::save);
```